# CORS error on bitballoon and Mongoose

Tags: mongoose, cors

I am not a web dev, But I need to test a WebGL game I'm making for a client on their platform.
Problem is I am getting a CORS errors when the site tries to play an audio file in my game.

This is what it says in Firefox console when it tries to play the sound.

[image]

I've been using either Mongoose or Bitballoon to test this. The benefit of these for me is that they are very simple to use.
Mongoose you just drag the exe into the folder u want to host and run it.
Bitballoon you just drag your files onto their site.
I dont know what CORS is and I dont care, I just wanna be able to test this game so I can ship it.

Is there anything like mongoose or bitballoon that wont have this CORS problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So CORS is enforced by the browser. The solution is to use chrome with an 'allow cors' plugin.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi